# Nodejs batch processing

Tags: node.js, batch-processing

A bit of conceptual question

I have 15 (for example) files that need to be processed. But i dont want to process them one at a time. Instead i want to start processing 5 of them (any 5 the order is not important) and as long one of these 5 files is processed another one to be started. The idea is to have max 5 files being processed at the same time until all files are processed.

Trying to work this out in Node but in general im missing the idea how this can be implemented

Comment: I can't right out a full answer right now, but check out the ChildProcess API. You basically want to spin up 5 sub processes and use the main process to feed work to them whenever they need it.

Comment: Unless you're talking about doing all this in the single thread in which case I'm not sure I see the benefit

Comment: I think you need to give us some sort of idea (code would be best) about what kind of processing you're trying to do on these files.  Is it CPU intensive or just disk intensive?  In other words, do you need to involve multiple CPUs or you just want to maximize the use of the main JS thread?

Comment: @david: There's still benefit doing this single threaded since the majority of the time the process will be waiting for I/O from disk

Comment: the processing is reading the files and enrich them with data from database. The database select is a bit nasty and on top of a large data and im trying to play nice (as far as i can) with the db. Dont want to run 15 selects at a time but dont want to process one at a time as well.

Comment: @slebetman Very true. In that case I'd simulate it with workers that pulled from some kind of stream/channel thing. Give me a min.

Answer (score 8):

A more accurate name for this type of processing might be 'limited parallel execution'. Mario Casciaro covers this well in his book, Node.js Design Patterns beginning on page 77. One use case for this pattern is when you want to control a set of parallel tasks that could cause excessive load. The example below is from his book.

**Limited Parallel Execution Pattern**

```
function TaskQueue(concurrency) {
  this.concurrency = concurrency;
  this.running = 0;
  this.queue = [];
}

TaskQueue.prototype.pushTask = function(task, callback) {
  this.queue.push(task);
  this.next();
}

TaskQueue.prototype.next = function() {
  var self = this;
  while(self.running < self.concurrency && self.queue.length) {
    var task = self.queue.shift();
    task(function(err) {
      self.running--;
      self.next();
    });
    self.running++;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Here's a little example that simulates multiple workers reading from a central queue of work: https://jsfiddle.net/ctrlfrk/jsvyg69h/1/

```
// Fake "work" that is simply a task that takes as many milliseconds as its value.
const workQueue = [1000,4000,2000,4000,5000,3000,7000,1000,9000,9000,4000,2000,1000,3000,8000,2000,3000,7000,6000,30000];


const Worker = (name) => (channel) => {
  const history = [];
  const next = () => {
    const job = channel.getWork();
    if (!job) { // All done!
      console.log('Worker ' + name + ' completed');
      return;
    }
    history.push(job);
    console.log('Worker ' + name + ' grabbed new job:' + job +'. History is:', history);

    window.setTimeout(next, job); //job is just the milliseconds.
  };
  next();
}

const Channel = (queue) => {
  return { getWork: () => {
    return queue.pop();
  }};
};

let channel = Channel(workQueue);
let a = Worker('a')(channel);
let b = Worker('b')(channel);
let c = Worker('c')(channel);
let d = Worker('d')(channel);
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do what you want by code below, but I am confused why you want to do this?

```
  function handle(file) {
    new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
      doSomething(file, function(err) {
        if(err)
          reject(err);
        else
          resolve();
      });
    })
    .then(function() {
      handle(files.shift());
    });
  }

  var files = [1, 2, ....., 15];
  var max = 5;
  while(max--) {
    handle(files.shift());
  }
```